# How to write a proper C# GET using Flurl

Tags: c#, flurl

How do I write my Flurl code to obtain this result, please ?

a. See, I have the header "Authorization" as in this image:
[image]

b. And I have these values in the body:

[image]

With these, my Get obtains this result [image]

So in C# I have this:

```
string clientID = ...;
string clientSecret = ...;
string authCredentials = $"{clientID}:{clientSecret}".Base64Encode(); //This value will be validated.

BearerToken result = serviceURL
   .AppendPathSegment("token")
   .WithHeaders(new
   {
      grant_type = "esslogin",
      ssusername = user,
      sspassword = password
   })
   .WithHeader("Authorization", $"Basic {authCredentials}")
   .GetJsonAsync<BearerToken>().Result;
```

Alas, I get "One or more errors occurred. (Call failed with status code 400 (Bad Request): GET https://demoservices64..../Login.Secured/token)

I have noticed that I would need to add the grant_type, ssusername, and sspassword into the body and not as params in the header.

How should I write the above using Flurl, please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a multiple issues here.

1. `grant_type`, `ssusername`, and `sspassword` should be passed in the body, not the headers, so don't use `WithHeaders`.
2. `GetJsonAsync` uses the HTTP `GET` method. But it looks like you want to simulate a form `POST`, so use `PostUrlEncodedAsync` instead. And, this method is where you pass the 3 values above. Example [here](https://flurl.dev/docs/fluent-http/).
3. Flurl provides a `WithBasicAuth` method so you don't need to format and encode the Authorization header yourself. Also demonstrated [here](https://flurl.dev/docs/fluent-http/).
4. To get the response body's deserialized JSON, you'll need to chain `ReceiveJson` at the very end, i.e.: `.PostUrlEncodedAsync(...).ReceiveJson<BearerToken>();`
5. Don't use `.Result`. It [invites deadlocks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Use `await`.